# Laravel switch case Undefined variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

This is my current view code. I don't know what's wrong with my code.

```
<?php

switch($_POST['selected']){
case 'option1':

break;
case 'option2':

case 'option3':

break;
default:

}
?>


<select name="selected">
 <option value="option1">hello world</option>
 <option value="option2">hello friend</option>
 <option value="option3">hello programming</option>
</select>
```

I get this error:

[image: Error]

Comment: Add an `isset()` check before performing the `switch()`

Comment: @JemwelBeltranLibron i think your $_POST['selected'] is not set properly.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of error messages. Post error text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, a variable or array element which has never been set is different from one whose value is null,  attempting to access such an unset value results in a runtime error.

That's what you're running into: the array $_POST does not have any element at the index "selected", so the interpreter aborts your program before it ever gets to the nullity test.

Fortunately, you can test for the existence of a variable or array element without actually trying to access it; that's what the special operator [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) does:

**change:**

```
switch($_POST['selected'])
```

**To:**

```
switch(isset($_POST['selected']))
```

Comment: Thank you but when i change like this  <?php
  
    switch(isset($_POST['selected'])){
    case 'option1':
         echo "hello";
    break;
    case 'option2':
       
    case 'option3':
         
    break;
    default:
        
    }

 ?> the echo wont display

Comment: @JemwelBeltranLibron it would be better execute the switch statement only if "selected" is set. So put the switch statement in an `if(($_POST['selected']))` condition

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 issues with your code.

1. One is as you are using POST variable in switch case, so you should have this switch case code in a if condition to execute only if $_POST['selected] is submitted.

   ```
   if(isset($_POST['selected'])){
      //complete switch case code
   }
   ```
2. Second issue i found is that you haven't break the case 'option2':
   [Second issue skip-able but you should follow standard practice]
   Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you dude, yeah i need to practice more :) i'm fresh programmer

Comment: it's OK Jemwel. In a bigger picture, A programmer is always a Learner.